# Define an OWL class to reflect the parameter list datatypes of a method's signature

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs

How might you define a subclass of an RDF List (yes, it needs to be an RDF List) such that it reflects the restrictions on the datatypes of a method signature's parameter list?

### For example

Given a method signature:

```
void set(uint, string);
```

Where an ABox statement would look like this:

```
# syntax: Turtle

("42"^^xsd:unsignedInt "Doug") a :SetCallArgumentList .
```

### My attempt

```
# syntax: Turtle

:SetCallArgumentList
    rdfs:subClassOf a owl:Class ;
    owl:intersectionOf (
        rdf:List
        [
            a owl:Restriction ;
            owl:onProperty rdf:first ;
            owl:cardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
            owl:allValuesFrom xsd:unsignedInt ;  # 1st parameter: uint
        ]
        [
            a owl:Restriction ;
            owl:onProperty rdf:rest ;
            owl:cardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
            owl:allValuesFrom [
                a owl:Class ;
                owl:intersectionOf rdf:List, [
                    a owl:Restriction ;
                    owl:onProperty rdf:first ;
                    owl:cardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
                    owl:allValuesFrom xsd:string ;  # 2nd parameter: string
                ], [
                    a owl:Restriction ;
                    owl:onProperty rdf:rest ;
                    owl:cardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
                    owl:hasValue rdf:nil ;  # end-of-list
                ] ;
            ] ;
        ] ;
    ) .
```

Are there any dangers, redundancies or oversights to what I've done here? Any comments are welcome.

Comment: I will answer this shortly. In the meantime you can look at Chapter 5 of my [dissertation](https://henrietteharmse.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/scenariotestingusingowl_v0-1-7-final.pdf) that explains all the details regarding the translation of methods to OWL.

Comment: For interest sake - what is your purpose for wanting to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assume we have a class `C` with a method `f(p1:P1, p2:P2):R` meaning `f` is a method taking parameters `p1` of type `P1` and `p2` of type `P2` returning something of type `R`. The types `P1`, `P2` and `R` can be data types or classes.

The basic idea is to introduce a class that will represent your method with its signature using reification. So we introduce a class, say `Method_f`, with properties `r_f`, `r_f_inv`, `r_p1`, `r_p2` and `r_R`. `r_f`. `r_f` is an object property with `r_f_inv` its inverse. `r_p1`, `r_p2` and `r_R` will be object properties or data properties depending on whether `P1`, `P2` and `R` are classes or data types. I.e. if `P1` is a class `r_p1` will be an object property, if it is a data type, `r_p1` will be a data property. Throughout I will use object properties.

[image: Reification representing method]

(1) The class `Method_f` must represent a tuple (consisting of 4 components in this case), for which we add the following axioms:

```
Class: Method_f
  SubClassOf:
    r_f_inv exactly 1 Thing and
    r_p1 exactly 1 Thing and
    r_p2 exactly 1 Thing and
    r_R exactly 1 Thing
```

(2) To ensure that a method for a given instance of a class `C` with given values for parameters `p1` and `p2` will not return different results, we add for class `Method_f` the following key:

```
  Haskey:
    r_f_inv, r_p1, r_p2
```

For methods not returning anything, the key is simply omitted.

(3) To ensure the parameters and return value has the correct types, the following axioms are added:

```
ObjectProperty: r_p1
  Domain: Method_f
  Range: P1
ObjectProperty: r_p2
  Domain: Method_f
  Range: P2
ObjectProperty: r_R
  Domain: Method_f
  Range: R
```

(4) To ensure that instances of the class `C` can invoke the method `f`, we add the axiom:

```
Class: C
  SubClassOf:
    r_f some Method_f
```

To represent the method `f` being invoked we have to:

(1) have instances of `C`, `P1`, `P2` and `R`, say `c`, `p1`, `p2`, `r`. 
(2) have an instance of `Method_f`:

```
Individual: method_f_call_1
  Types: Method_f
  Facts: 
    r_f_inv c,
    r_p1 p1,
    r_p2 p2,
    r_R r
```

(3) invoke it.

```
Individual: c
  Types: C
  Facts: r_f method_f_call_1
```

For a detailed explanation regarding this, see Chapter 5 of my [dissertation](https://henrietteharmse.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/scenariotestingusingowl_v0-1-7-final.pdf).

Comment: Interesting work, the approach seems rather robust. However, where is the parameter order being preserved? I would expect, for example, to see a linked list somewhere.

Comment: Order is not preserved. The purpose here is to enable logical verification and validation of models, as well as finding modeling heuristic violations. Parameter order is not important in these instances. Parameter order is of importance for implementation details, which cannot be modelled effectively using OWL.

Comment: What is your purpose for wanting to model methods in OWL?

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. I realize that I really have two separate needs, one is for validation and the other is to encode function calls in RDF. I think something like the [Function Ontology](https://users.ugent.be/~bjdmeest/function/#fn-expects) will suffice for the latter.